# Commands not found

Tags: python, discord.py

Hello so I was trying to make a discord bot using python and for some reason it can't find the commands!

```
import os
from discord.ext import commands
import discord
from loguru import logger
import logging

import json

with open("data/database.json") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

token = data["token"]
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=['$', 't!'], case_insensitive=True, intents=discord.Intents.all())
client.remove_command('help')


def load_cogs():
    for file in os.listdir("cogs"):
        if file.endswith(".py"):
            name = file[:-3]
            client.load_extension(f"cogs.{name}")
            logger.info(f"Loaded cogs.{name}")



load_cogs()

client.run(token)
```

I tried to change the way it read the files but nothing worked

Comment: There are a few things to check: have you enabled the message content intent in your discord developper portal and do your files have the `setup(bot)` function? It is important to note that message commands are deprecated, you could switch to slash commands.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and the your method of actually reading files worked fine. Your problem is how you are calling the `load_cogs()` function. By calling `load_cogs()` asynchronously in the `on_ready()` event, your cogs will be loaded as expected.

I rewrote some of your code to demonstrate:

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await load_cogs()

async def load_cogs():
    for file in os.listdir("cogs"):
        if file.endswith(".py"):
            name = file[:-3]
            await client.load_extension(f"cogs.{name}")
            print(f"Loaded cogs.{name}")

client.run(token)
```

Let me know if you have any questions or problems. Have a great day/night!